# ASP.NET Core MVC, Identity, Custom policy - Problem with custom authorization, policy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-authorization

I want to add a policy so that every user expect the ones with role "Admin" could use a controller. Below is my code. When I type **[Authorize(Policy="NotAdmin")]** over my controller class, then actually every person (no matter if is admin or not) has access denied to actions from the controller. I use Visual Studio 2022 and .NET 6.0. In my project I use Identity, I have class ApplicationUser which extends IdentityUser class.

```
 public class NotAdminRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
     
     
    }

public class NotAdminHandler : AuthorizationHandler<NotAdminRequirement>
    {
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, NotAdminRequirement requirement)
        {
            var user = context.User;

            if (!user.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            } 

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

**In Program.cs:**

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("NotAdmin", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new NotAdminRequirement()));
});
```

Comment: Are you currently denied access to the API as a user with any permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, NotAdminHandler>();
```

Comment: Before mentioning it as an answer, it should be asked in the questions comment section.